# Generate Hierarchical data for a Neo4j node entity

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

**following details will describe my problem.**

Framework:Spring boot 

Database: Neo4j Embedded mode

Repository: GraphRepository

Below is my Organization POJO

```
@NodeEntity
public class Organization extends UserBaseEntity {

   @NotNull(message = "error.Organization.name.notnull")
   private String name;
   private String email;

   @Relationship(type = HAS_SUB_ORGANIZATION)
   private List<Organization> children = new ArrayList<>();

 // getter and setters
}
```

**Tried so Far:**
Using findOne with specific depth.

for example:
    graphRepo.findOne(organizationId,3);
 This will return full network of organization.

I Need to generate hierarchy data for Organization. 
Is there any way to make recursive query to generate Organization hierarchy.

**I need just id,name,children(Sub-Organization)**

**Sample format**

```
[
    {
      id: 1,
     name: 'Organization 1',
      children: [
        { id: 2, name: 'Organization 1 ' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Organization 2' }
      ]
    },
   {
     id: 4,
     name: 'Organization 2',
     children: [
       { 
          id: 5,
          name: 'Organization 2 unit'
       }

     ]
   }
 ]
```

Comment: Have you tried using a custom repository query with the `@Query` annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you a solution I implemented in my application like below:
First, define a OrganizationDTO for mapping data.

```
Class OrganizationDTO {
private String code;
private String name;
private List<OrganizationDTO> children;
//Add setter and getter
```

}
Then, modified your repository with your cypher query:

```
@Repository
public class OrganisationRepositoryImpl implement OrganisationRepository {

    private final Neo4jUtils neo4jUtils;


    List<Organisation> findOrg(String orgCode) {

        Map<String, Object> params = map("orgCode", orgCode);

         String query = "MATCH (n:Organisation)-[r:HAS_SUB_ORGANIZATION*]->(m:Organisation) "+
        " where n.code = {orgCode} return " +
        " n.code, "+
        " n.name, "+ 
        " m is not null haschildren ," +
        " m as children" +
    return neo4jUtils.cypher(query, params)
                .map(this::mapToOrganization)
                .collect(toList());
    }

    private OrganizationDTO mapToOrganization(Map<String, Object> map) {
        OrganizationDTO org = new OrganizationDTO(
            map.get("n.code"), map.get("n.name"));
        if((Boolean)map.get("haschildren")){
            org.setChilren(m.get("children");
        }

    }
}
```

When Rest API implemented, the OrganizationDTO responds a JSON format as your expected. I hope that this can help you.